# Construir query no Laravel

Tags: laravel

```
    `update `table` set is_available = 0 where id_restaurant = 303 (and weekday = ? or id = ? )`

    $weekday = $request->input('weekday', '');
    $table = $request->input("id", ''); 


//Query em construção        
    DB::table('table')
      ->where('id_restaurant', $this->restaurantId)
      ->update(['is_available' => 0]);
```

**parâmetros entre parênteses são opcionais, quando os parâmetros weekday e id não existirem quero atualizar a tabela where o id_restaurant seja igual a 303** como construir essa query no Laravel ?

Comment: O que você tentou até agora?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: @gmsantos, pode dar uma olhada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Voê pode fazer uma simples verificação na request para saber o valor sendo retornado**

---

```
if(($request->input('weekday') == '') && ($request->input('id') == '')) {
  //Se for vazio seta para 303
      DB::table('table')
      ->where('id_restaurant', '303')
      ->update(['is_available' => 0]);
}
```

> Recomendo dar uma lida na documentação para entender melhor o [Query
>   Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) do laravel